# Using sockets to read from client side

Tags: c, unix, sockets, client

I basically have a server set up and I'm accepting new clients(UNIX) and i'm using select() command to wait for activity on file descriptor but I'm not sure how to write from the clients side and then read it on the servers side

```
FD_ZERO(&readfds);
FD_SET(server_sockfd, &readfds);
FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &readfds); 
while (1) {
   testfds = readfds;
   select(4 + MAXCLIENTS, &testfds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
   for (fd = 0; fd < 4 + MAX_CLIENTS; fd++) {
     if (FD_ISSET(fd, &testfds)) {
        if (fd == server_sockfd) { /* new connection request */
           client_sockfd = accept(server_sockfd, NULL, NULL);
           if (num_clients < MAXCLIENTS) {
              FD_SET(client_sockfd, &readfds);
              num_clients++;
           } else {
              sprintf(message, "XSorry, too many clients.  Try again later.\n");
              write(client_sockfd, message, strlen(message));
              close(client_sockfd);
           }
        } else if (fd == STDIN_FILENO) { 
           fgets(kb_message, BUFSIZ + 1, stdin);
           if (strcmp(kb_message, "quit\n") == 0) {
              sprintf(message, "XServer is shutting down.\n");
              for (fd2 = 4; fd2 < 4 + MAX_CLIENTS; fd2++) {
                 if (FD_ISSET(fd2, &readfds)) {
                    write(fd2, message, strlen(message));
                    close(fd2);
                 }
              }
              close(server_sockfd);
              exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
           } else {
              sprintf(message, "M%s", kb_message);
              for (fd2 = 4; fd2 < 4 + MAX_CLIENTS; fd2++)
                 if (FD_ISSET(fd2, &readfds))
                    write(fd2, message, strlen(message));
           }
        } else { /* client leaving */
           close(fd);
           FD_CLR(fd, &readfds);
           num_clients--;
        }
     }
  }
```

}

How would I handle write request from clients and then write back to them, would it be under "else" and how can I check if client is exiting or writing.

Thanks

Comment: @Roberto: You might want to re-edit the code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in thinking you need the read code in your 'else' block. If a file descriptor triggers and it isn't stdin or the 'connect' descriptor, then it is one of your clients attempting to send you data. When one of those file descriptors is triggered in the select, you need to call 'read' on that descriptor to read the data into the buffer. The read command will return you the number of bytes read. If this is a positive number, then it indicates the client has sent you data. If it is zero, then that indicates that the client has ended the TCP connection to your server.

The else block will look something like:

```
 else 
  {
     //Existing connection has data for us to read
     if((nBytes = read(fd, buffer, MAXBUFFER)) <= 0) 
     {
        if(nBytes == 0)
        {
          //Actually, its sending us zero bytes, connection closed
          printf("Socket %d hung up\n", fd;
        }
     else
          printf ("Read Error"\n)
  }
```

Also, Follow Nikolai N Fetissov's advice above and make sure that when client's connect you store their fd in a permanent fd_set structure, as the one you are using is being modified by the select call.

Answer (score 2):

The most common mistake with `select(2)` is ***not re-initializing the descriptor sets***, since second, third, and forth arguments are *input-output parameters*.

Setup an `fd_set`, for reading before the outer loop, add listening socket descriptor to it, enter the loop, *make a copy* of the this `fd_set` and give the copy to `select(2)`. When new connection arrives, add its descriptor to the *original* `fd_set`. Same for closed socket (error or EOF on `read(2)`) - remove the descriptor from the *original* `fd_set`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be that you have a variable called `read`.  It's going to mask one of hte functions you need to use - the `read()` system call to get data out of the socket.  The client puts it in with `write()`.  You might also want to check the return value from `select()`, which will tell you how many of the file descriptors are ready for reading.  Then you can check which ones using `FD_ISSET()`.  It looks like you're doing that part already (except you seem to be checking the wrong variable?)... just call `read()` on that file descriptor to get out the data the client wrote.

Comment: That's probably just a typo, he's using `readfds` in the loop after `select(2)`.

Comment: @Nikolai, yeah that's true.  There's some weird casing on `StDIN_FILENO`, too.  I guess this isn't the real code.

Answer (score 0):

```
else 
{
  bzero(buf,100);
     n=read(i,buf,100); // Read the client message 
            buf[n]='\0';
       if(n==0) // Check the client is closed or not 
      {

              printf("%d is closed\n",i);
              close(i);
              FD_CLR(i, &master);
              if(i==fdmax)
              fdmax--;

       }
       else
       {
            n=strlen(buf);

        write(1,buf,n);
        fflush(stdout);

          write(1,"Enter the message\n",18);
          bzero(buf,100);
          read(0,buf,100);
            buf[n]='\0';
          write(i,buf,n);
          fflush(stdout);
       }
    }
```

Notes: 
    After accept the client, Add the client in the fd set. 
    Then read the message from the client 
    If the message is equal to 0, then the client is closed. 
    If you want to send the message to the client, using the client fd, you can send to the client